# Can't get keypressed method to work

Tags: java, jpanel, keylistener

I am just trying to experiment with the keypressed method and make sure it works before I continue and do more complicated things with my program. At the moment, I am just trying to make the class that implements Keylistener add an image to the JPanel when the user presses the left arrow key. I have put the relevant code below.

```
public class Game implements KeyListener, ActionListener{

    private Window window;
    private JLabel enemySpaceshipLabel;
    private JPanel panel;


    public Game(){
        indexEnemySpaceship = (int)(Math.random()*7);
        try {
            enemySpaceshipLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("spaceship (" + indexEnemySpaceship + ").png"))));
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        window = new Window("Space Game")
        panel = window.getPanel();
        panel.addKeyListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)   
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
            panel.add(enemySpaceshipLabel);
            panel.repaint();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {        
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Window extends JFrame{

    private JPanel panel;

    public Window(String title){
        SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread();
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        panel = new JPanel();
        this.add(panel);
        this.pack();
        this.setSize(500,500); //my edit
        panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        this.setVisible(true);

    }

    public JPanel getPanel() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return panel;
    }

}
```

Comment: Favor the key bindings API over `KeyListener`, it solves the focus related issues which it suffers from - see [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more details

Comment: [Similar questions](https://www.google.com/#q=site:stackoverflow.com+java+swing+keylistener+jpanel+not+working)

Comment: I would rather get the KeyListener to method to work than to go off and use something else. After all, if other people are able to use it, I don't see why I shouldn't be able to use it as well.

Comment: @jmao But other people can't get it to work (reliably), this is why there are so many posts about "why doesn't my key listener work?" - typically with answers describing the fact that `KeyListener` is generally a poor/incorrect choice for the job they are trying to do, which was replaced/updated with the Key Bindings API to help fix it way back in Java 1.4 - but, if you want to continue struggling with an API which isn't designed to achieve the results you're after, that is of course your choose and I wish you the best of luck with it ... hope you're not attached to your hair ;)

Comment: My hair? OK, thank you for your advice. I will look up the Key Bindings API.